# DOCX4J: How add rows to existing table in docx template?

Tags: java, docx4j

I need add rows to existing table in docx template. How it make? Please share code.

Answer (score 2):

Use Word (or whatever) to create a docx containing only a table with the row you want to add.

Then upload it [here](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html); click through to the document.xml part; then click on the w:tbl element hyperlink.

That'll generate suitable code for you.  To understand more, look at docx4j's Getting Started guide.